# Xcode 12.3 issue with Cocoa Pods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

if you try to install Cocoa pods while you have Xcode 12.3 you will probably get the error below:

```
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

package configuration for libffi is not found
"xcrun clang -o conftest -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/universal-darwin19 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/backward -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_ATOMIC_BUILTINS conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib -L. -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.Internal.sdk/usr/local/lib   -arch x86_64   -lruby.2.6   "
    In file included from conftest.c:1:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby.h:33:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found
    #include "ruby/config.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: note: did not find header 'config.h' in framework 'ruby' (loaded from '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks')
    1 error generated.
    checked program was:
    /* begin */
    1: #include "ruby.h"
    2: 
    3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
    4: {
    5:   return 0;
    6: }
    /* end */
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you need to:

- make sure you have [Command Line Tools for Xcode 12.3](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)
- to install Cocoa Pods on your MacOS use the following:

```
    sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods -v 1.8.4
```

Latest CocoaPods 1.10.0 won't work.

In order to update to latest version you need to use [brew commands](https://formulae.brew.sh/)

then enter the command below:

```
brew install cocoapods
```

Comment: I dont see why CocoaPods 1.10.0 should not work with Xcode 12.3? I also dont agree in installing Cocoapods with brew. Cocoapods comes as a gem and can be perfectly installed as such.

Comment: Same here, but unfortunately this is what happens and you can see this issue occurring in a lot of articles online and on apple developer site :(